# MVC4 - Need to pass back an ID depending on link pressed

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a navigation menu with the following menu items

- Assets
- Environment
- Processes

Each of these menu items is held in a table in my database named RiskType

**RiskType Table**

- ID
- Description

When a menu item is clicked on, it will display a view which contains a table, the table will contain all the associated data for that Risk Type.

There are only 3 Risk Types and instead of creating 3 separate views to display the associated data for each risk type, I would like to use a single view. At the moment I've hard coded each of the Risk Type IDs into it's ActionLink like so..

**ActionLinks**

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Assets", "ViewRiskTypes", "RiskTypeDetails", new { SelectedRiskTypeID = 0}, null)</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Enviromental", "ViewRiskTypes", "RiskTypeDetails", new { SelectedRiskTypeID = 1 }, null)</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Processes", "ViewRiskTypes", "RiskTypeDetails", new { SelectedRiskTypeID = 2 }, null)</li>
```

**Action Controller**

```
   public ActionResult ViewRiskTypes(int SelectedRiskTypeID)
        {
            var RiskTypes = _DBContext.RiskTypes.ToList();
            var ViewModel = new List<RiskTypeWithDetails>();  

            foreach (var RiskType in RiskTypes) 
            {
                if (RiskType.ID == SelectedRiskTypeID)
                {
                    var Details = new RiskTypeWithDetails();
                    Details.RiskTypeDescription = RiskType.Description;  
                    Details.RiskDetails = _DBContext
                                          .RiskTypeHasGroups
                                          .Where(r => r.RiskTypeID == SelectedRiskTypeID) 
                                          .Select(r => new RiskDetails
                                          {
                                              RiskGroupDescription = r.RiskGroup.Description,
                                              GroupType = r.RiskGroup.RiskGroupHasGroupTypes 
                                                        .Select(v => v.GroupType).ToList(),
                                              //GroupTypeName = r.RiskGroup.RiskGroupHasGroupTypes.Select(v => v.GroupType.Name).ToList(),
                                              Owner = r.RiskGroup.RiskGroupHasGroupTypes.Select(v => v.GroupType.Owner).ToList()
                                          }).ToList();

                    ViewModel.Add(Details);
                }
            }
            return View(ViewModel);
        }
```

This isn't ideal since an administrator could potentially add new Risk Types or remove existing ones.

I understand that I will need to pass the selected Risk Types ID into the Views Action Control, but am unsure the best way to do this if anyone could offer some suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: why not create action links from db instead of hardcoding?and instead of if statement only get related risktype  from db `DBContext.RiskTypes.Where(x=>x.RiskTypeID==selectedID)`

Comment: Yep I don't want to use the hard coded action links, what do you mean by "create action links from db instead of hard coding", this is what am unsure how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view that renders the action links should have a view model. This view model will need to contain a list of risk types that you populate from your database. For example, something like this:

**Class for risk type items**

```
public class RiskTypeItem
{
    public int ID { get;set; }
    public string Name { get;set;}
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ActionsModel
{
    public List<RiskTypeItem> RiskTypes { get; set; }

    public ActionsModel()
    {
        RiskTypes = new List<RiskTypeItem>();
    }
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
ActionsModel model = new ActionsModel();
var riskTypes = _DBContext.RiskTypes.ToList();

foreach(var riskType in riskTypes)
{
    model.RiskTypes.Add(new RiskTypeItem { ID = riskType.ID, Name = riskType.Name });
}

return ActionResult(model);
```

**View**

```
// First line.
@model ActionsModel
//...other stuff...
<ul>
@foreach(var riskType in Model.RiskTypes)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(riskType.Name, "ViewRiskTypes", "RiskTypeDetails", new { SelectedRiskTypeID = riskType.ID }, null)</li>
}
</ul>
```

If you already use a ViewModel for this particular view then just modify that one to add the new property for `RiskTypes` list.

Comment: Thanks for the great example this is exactly what I was looking for. More than enough to help me understand.